# How can I get eredis to compile?

Tags: erlang

I am new to the world of erlang and phoenix. Anyways, I am trying to figure out a compiling issue and I have hit wits end for now.

I will do my best to provide as much information as possible to help with this problem. If I've missed anything just let me know.

When running the command `mix deps.get` everything is compiled properly from my `mix.exs`.

However, once I run `mix conform.configure`

I get the error:

```
==> eredis (compile)
include/eredis_sub.hrl:19: type queue() undefined
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency eredis, /usr/bin/rebar command failed. If you want to recompile this dependency, please run: mix deps.compile eredis
```

Running `mix dep.compile eredis` produces the same error as above.

Oh and I am running erlang 18. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Either use v17, or change to queue:queue().

Answer (score 1):

Use `rebar compile` instead of `make`. `Makefile` of `eredis` is [broken](https://github.com/wooga/eredis/issues/75). They are probably using `eredis` exclusively as subproject and is no longer compiled using `make`.

And as well update to at least [v1.7.0](https://github.com/wooga/eredis/releases/tag/v1.0.7) but preferably [v1.0.8](https://github.com/wooga/eredis/releases/tag/v1.0.8).